# CS student working on first website, having issues with phpmailer on hostinger

Tags: php, html

I've finally built my first website and gotten the hosting figured out. As stated in the title I'm using hostinger and phpmailer, I have never used PHP so I went through their short tutorial and got the PHP file set up how I feel is the correct way.

The issue I'm having is that when I submit the form, I get an error page. Nothing in the network tab on chrome suggests that it is trying to send any data, although it does show it opening the PHP file, *I think*, again this is my first website and first time using PHP.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'hostinger-email@domain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password for hostinger email';
    $mail->setFrom('same-as-username??', 'Admin');
    $mail->addAddress('destination@gmail.com', 'Savannah');
    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer contact form';
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Name: {$_POST['name']}
Message: {$_POST['message']}
EOT;
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Share it with us!';
    }
?>
```

---

**HTML FORM:**

```
<header class="form_header">Contact Me</header>

<form id="form" class="topBefore" action="/domains/piecesofblonde.com/public_html/formscript.php" method="post">
                
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">
    <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL">
    <textarea id="message" type="text" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO!">
          
</form>
```

Comment: What is your domain name? Why does your action attribute in the form seem like a physical file path?

Comment: _"I get an error page"_ That says... what?

Comment: stupid questions don't exist, everyone started at some point, however, the first half of your question isn't a question (CS student ...)

Comment: Change your form action attribute to just `/formscript.php`

Comment: @nice_dev I've tried so many different ways of linking the php file, linking it like that actually found the file. What is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: @AlexHowansky It just gives me the http error 500 page, is there somewhere else I could look for debugging information? I've looked in the developer console and all I can really see is whether or not pressing "submit" actually brings me to the php file.

Comment: @MartinToms Fair point, I guess I'm apprehensive towards the toxicity of stack overflow. And I really just wanted to fully explain my problem before asking anything.

Comment: @nice_dev that was what I had initially, it still gives me an http error 500 page.

Comment: You seem to be missing a starting single quote in addAddress

Comment: @nice_dev Fortunately that was just an error I made when bringing the code over to stack exchange.

Comment: PHP 500 error pages are generic. You'll need to look at your web server's logs for more info.

Comment: Yes, you will need to check logs if error is still persisting. Turn on error reporting if it was off.

Comment: @nice_dev They were off! this is the error code is given, I know it has something to do with either my file structure or the way I'm linking to the PHP file, but I can't tell what exactly it means.

Comment: @nice_dev [02-Sep-2020 20:58:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/u797918978/domains/piecesofblonde.com/public_html/formscript.php on line 3

Comment: Is vendor in the same level as formscript.php? Do they have the right permissions to read the file?

Comment: @nice_dev I think you've just found my dumb mistake. I don't have a PHP file by that name in my codebase. I deleted that line and was told that it had to be there for the line above it to run.

Comment: Restore that line. You will need to download PHPmailer and add that folder there. It seems you don't have the plugin.

Comment: @nice_dev I feel like I'm not following you 100%, download PHPmailer as in the entire thing, and add the file? Or download PHPmailer and add the vendor file into my directory?

Comment: @nice_dev Awe man, I don't have composer on my hostinger server. I thought it was pre-installed on all plans, but not the one that I have. I'm going to manually install it and get back to you. Thanks to all for the help

Comment: @nice_dev I'm not sure what I'm missing here, I need to install composer on the server for the vendor/autoload.php, and from what I've read the only way to do this is through ssh access, which you don't have with the shared hosting plan. I'm stumped at this point but would really hate to tell this person that I have to remove the contact form.

Comment: One workaround would be to install composer and install the plugin on your local machine and then just put the entire folder from your local machine to live site.